# how do i remove registration link in joomla 3.2 - login module

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

i need to remove the registration link inside the login view http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php/login without completely disabling the registration functionality.

We are using js Jobs on the site and the regular registration is not providing all fields, therefore i need to find the code where i simply can delete the registration link.

I looked inside the modules and plugins, but couldn't find it

Anyone has an idea where i can find that code?

Comment: I'd just write a plugin to redirect anytime someone attempts to go to the original login page, it's a never ending battle if you try to do it piecemeal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find the registration-link in /components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php on the bottom of the file. You can override this file in your own template by copying it to /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login/default_login.php. Then you can remove the registration-line from the file in your template,

regards Jonas

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That did the trick. I did create the folders within my template directory, perfect solution THUMBS UP :)